# How do I install and setup RESTSharp without NuGet?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I am using Visual Studio C# 2010 Express and is learning.  RESTSharp is supposed to be installed by NuGet but NuGet cannot be used with Express version.  Can I still install and configure RESTSharp manually, and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NuGet Visual Studio plugin can't be used with Express, but you can [install NuGet packages from the command line](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html). You'll need to download the command line bootstrapper from the [NuGet CodePlex site](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939).

After installing it, you can just use

```
nuget Install SomePackageName
```

and it will fetch the package and its dependencies to local disk. You'll need to add the project references manually though, AFAIK.

Comment: Cool will try this!  I added reference to the dll from older version.  Seems to work, but I will try your suggestion so I can use the newer one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Get the dll from https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/downloads

and add it as reference to your project

Comment: But that link shows that the github downloads were discontinued in Sept 2012.

Comment: 404 - That link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the code from github and compile it

Comment: The binaries are also on the github download page.