# How can I install RESTSharp in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-web-api, compact-framework, windows-ce, restsharp

I'm sold on at least checking out RESTSharp. I need it for a Windows CE / Compact Framework 3.5 app to connect to some WebAPI methods. This: http://thechangelog.com/restsharp-simple-rest-and-http-api-client-for-net/ says, "Perhaps most impressive is RestSharp’s support for a number of environments including .NET 3.5+" so I'm ready to go. However, this: http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp says, "To install RestSharp, run the following command in the Package Manager Console" and Visual Studio 2008 has no Package Manager extravaganza.

Tools > Find More Extensions... > searching for "Restsharp" gives me only "Callisto" (why, I don't know)

So how can I install RESTSharp in VS 2008?

### UPDATE

Okay, I installed NuGet as a command line, added it to VS 2008 via Tools > External Tools, and set it up this way:

[image]

...but when I subsequently select "NuGet" from Tools > NuGet, and add "Install-Package RestSharp" in the Arguments edit box, I get, "Unknown command: 'Install-Package'"

What is the proper usage?

### UPDATE 2

Trying to install using the command line tool also fails:

[image]

If I 2-click nuget.exe in Windows Explorer, its console "flashes" for a millisecond (or so) and then disappears.

### UPDATE 3

Jon Skeet's answer here: [How do I install and setup RESTSharp without NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630685/how-do-i-install-and-setup-restsharp-without-nuget)

...led to the era of good feelings for me:

[image]

Comment: You can install [NuGet as a command-line tool](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) (see the *command-line utility* link) outside of Visual Studio, and then get RestSharp that way

Comment: I'm updating my question with another related question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those aren't the command line arguments.  You run NuGet, which opens a console.  You then enter the "Install-Package..." command.  You might be able to check "Use Output Window" and uncheck the Prompt For Arguments".  I'm not sure, I just run it from a command console window if I need a VS'08 package.

Comment: Checking "Use Output Window" just throws up a lot of verbiage, but is readonly. I've updated again.